# How to find out who is calling futex system call on Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, system-calls

I start several pthreads and every thread keep running function like below:

```
void test_spin() {
    pthread_spin_lock(&spinlock);
    pthread_spin_unlock(&spinlock);
}
```

a simple 'strace -c -f' shows me that there are 3 futex system calls. So my question here is where does these system call come from? And how can I trace who is calling the futex system call?

Comment: You might use `ltrace` or study the source code of your libc implementation, probably [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried ltrace, nothing valuable, the output cannot help me connect the link between user land functions and the system call. Perhaps what can I do now is just dive into glibc code.

Comment: BTW, why do you ask and why do you care? You need to explain that in your question, so **edit your question** to improve and motivate it. If you want POSIX threads, use POSIX thread primitives without caring about how they are implemented using futexes (which are an implementation detail).